US keyboard layout is not shown under the choice of keyboard languages
In my Windows-11 In the Settings, I see as installed language packs    English (United States) and
English (United Kingdom), and   several other languages.  In the Language Bar  I see for English only
English (United Kingdom)  Both US and UK in the  Settings app  have the  "basic typing" language option shown as "Installed".  How do I switch my keyboard to the US English?

I assume you want these other language packs and keyboard layouts installed?

To add a keyboard layout, see https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-add-change-keyboard-layouts/ and  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-the-input-and-display-language-settings-in-windows-12a10cb4-8626-9b77-0ccb-5013e0c7c7a2,
